# How to create a IO object from a file?

Tags: ruby, io

Another seems stupid question, but haven't found a clear example.

I need a IO object as parameter for a function, [actually its the new function in this class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/UI/Console/TestRunner.html):

I used this way , but seems some problems when using a file descriptor as a IO after wrote something:

```
irb(main):001:0> f= File.open("result.txt","w")
=> #<File:result.txt>
irb(main):002:0> i=IO.new(f.to_i,"w")
=> #<IO:0x3b5cb90>
irb(main):003:0> i.write "hello the world"
=> 15
irb(main):004:0> i.close
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> f.close
Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor - result.txt
        from (irb):5:in `close'
        from (irb):5
        from :0
```

So I only need to close either i or f once? or there is a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`FILE` is a subclass of `IO`

```
irb(main):001:0> File.superclass
=> IO
```

In your case, i and f refer to the same object. Hence the observation. You can use the File object for TestRunner.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like this:

```
File.open("result.txt", 'w') do |f|
  t = TestRunner.new(your_suite, NORMAL, f)
  t.start
end
```

This will start the test running using the result.txt file io object. It will automatically close the file even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I am stupid... why forget this example after saw it... Thanks!